# Under tornado v4+ WebSocket connections get refused with 403

Tags: nginx, websocket, tornado

I have an older tornado server that handles vanilla WebSocket connections. I proxy these connections, via Nginx, from wss://info.mydomain.com to wss://mydomain.com:8080 in order to get around customer proxies that block non standard ports.

After the recent upgrade to Tornado 4.0 all connections get refused with a 403. What is causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Tornado 4.0 introduced an, on by default, same origin check. This checks that the origin header set by the browser is the same as the host header

The [code looks like:](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/websocket.py#L274)

```
 def check_origin(self, origin):
    """Override to enable support for allowing alternate origins.

    The ``origin`` argument is the value of the ``Origin`` HTTP header,
    the url responsible for initiating this request.

    .. versionadded:: 4.0
    """
    parsed_origin = urlparse(origin)
    origin = parsed_origin.netloc
    origin = origin.lower()

    host = self.request.headers.get("Host")

    # Check to see that origin matches host directly, including ports
    return origin == host
```

In order for your proxied websocket connection to still work you will need to override check origin on the WebSocketHandler and whitelist the domains that you care about. Something like this.

```
import re
from tornado import websocket

class YouConnection(websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return bool(re.match(r'^.*?\.mydomain\.com', origin))
```

This will let the connections coming through from `info.mydomain.com` to get through as before.

Comment: Note that this [was documented](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/releases/v4.0.0.html#backwards-compatibility-notes) in the release notes for 4.0.

Comment: Yup, but it took me a long time to figure out that it was a tornado upgrade that was causing this behaviour in our integration environment. Hence why I'm documenting it.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to propose and alternative solution, instead of messing with the tornado application code, I solved the issue by telling nginx to fix the host header:

```
location /ws {
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_pass http://backend;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that this effectively disables all cross origin protection for this socket. Potentially creating a security risk.

Comment: how come? host is $host

Comment: Oh right, I see that now. We must have had different problems then. Because my Origin header and Host header didn't match. Which was to be expected.

Comment: you could still add a check for $host and fix, just be careful http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil