# how can I implement a WebSocket using Tornado on a live server instead of localhost

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, tornado

I'm new to using WebSockets, and have so far been limited to using them via localhost and developing everything locally. I have followed this tutorial for live data visualisation:
https://medium.com/@benjaminmbrown/real-time-data-visualization-with-d3-crossfilter-and-websockets-in-python-tutorial-dba5255e7f0e

I worked through the tutorial (all of the scripts are available from the GitHub link in the article) and it works perfectly via localhost. However, I have some website space on which I am able to put the main index script which works when the WebSocket script is running on the same local machine that is displaying the website in the browser (in this case listening to localhost 8001), but I am struggling to figure out how to use a WebSocket with a live server rather than just via the local host method in this article! I would like to be able to access the webpage that displays the live data from any computer through my website, i.e there is one computer running the WebSocket that is unrelated to the computer(s) which displays the website in their browser. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I think that I specifically need help with rewriting the `websocket.py` script such that the information is being fed to a server, i.e [www.examplewebsite.com](http://www.examplewebsite.com), which I can then access via my index file page at [www.examplewebsite.com/index.html](http://www.examplewebsite.com/index.html) using the js in my index file:

```
var connection = new WebSocket('wss://examplewebsite.com/blank:8001/websocket');
```

or something similar, as opposed to

```
 var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8001/websocket');
```

in the original version, but I am unsure how to establish this when setting up the WebSocket using the existing code in order to listen there in the index file. When running the WebSocket on my local machine, the live webpage successfully displays the live updating data, however, if someone else (who is not running the WebSocket) goes to the same page they will not see live data.

The `websocket.py` script is as follows:

```
import time
import random
import json
import datetime
import os
from tornado import websocket, web, ioloop
from datetime import timedelta
from random import randint

paymentTypes = ["cash", "tab", "visa","mastercard","bitcoin"]
namesArray = ['Ben', 'Jarrod', 'Vijay', 'Aziz']


class WebSocketHandler(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
  # Addition for Tornado as of 2017, need the following method
  # per: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851207/tornado-403-get-warning-when-opening-websocket/25071488#25071488
  def check_origin(self, origin):
    return True

  #on open of this socket
  def open(self):
    print ('Connection established.')
    #ioloop to wait for 3 seconds before starting to send data
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3), self.send_data)

 #close connection
  def on_close(self):
    print ('Connection closed.')

  def check_origin(self, origin):
    return True

  # Our function to send new (random) data for charts
  def send_data(self):
    print ("Sending Data")
    #create a bunch of random data for various dimensions we want
    qty = random.randrange(1,4)
    total = random.randrange(30,1000)
    tip = random.randrange(10, 100)
    payType = paymentTypes[random.randrange(0,4)]
    name = namesArray[random.randrange(0,4)]
    spent = random.randrange(1,150);
    year = random.randrange(2012,2016)

    #create a new data point
    point_data = {
        'quantity': qty,
        'total' : total,
        'tip': tip,
        'payType': payType,
        'Name': name,
        'Spent': spent,
        'Year' : year,
        'x': time.time()
    }

    print (point_data)

    #write the json object to the socket
    self.write_message(json.dumps(point_data))

    #create new ioloop instance to intermittently publish data
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(datetime.timedelta(seconds=1), self.send_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  #create new web app w/ websocket endpoint available at /websocket
  print ("Starting websocket server program. Awaiting client requests to open websocket ...")
  application = web.Application([(r'/static/(.*)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': os.path.dirname(__file__)}),
                                 (r'/websocket', WebSocketHandler)])
  application.listen(8001)
  ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

The Github link to all the tutorial scripts, I am using `index.html` and `websocket.py`: https://github.com/benjaminmbrown/real-time-data-viz-d3-crossfilter-websocket-tutorial/tree/master/rt-data-viz

NOTE: In my version, I have replaced some of the randomly generated numbers in the `websocket.py` script with numbers generated by an external device so the WebSocket must be established in python on the machine connected to said external device.

Answer (score 0):

Your web socket server should run on a system that can be found via DNS by a **hostname** or **IP address** and listen there on port 8001 for connections.

Let’s say this system can be found (ping, nslookup) at **local.host.home**, then change

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://local.host.home:8001/websocket');
```

Now the server should feed any client that connects.

Comment: Do you mean that if I have some website, www.example.com/index.html and can create another page, www.example.com/blank that I could use 

`var connection = new WebSocket('ws://example.com/blank:8001/websocket');`

does this change the python code for the WebSocket itself?

Comment: First of all I don’t know python, however if you have a system you can reach over the network, move you web socket server code there and try to start it. You don’t need a webserver on that system. 
Within your server script, print out the name on the host your python server is listening for connection.
Use this hostname in:
`var connection = new WebSocket('ws://host.name:8001/websocket');`

Comment: I think specifically my issue is how to re-write the above code (websocket.py) such that it is feeding the data to my server, i.e how to change the location of the WebSocket in the script that sets up the WebSocket to somewhere other than my localhost, rather than how to read the information at the other end via the js script